# Django: How to use output of dumpdata for a DB that has more rows added/isn't completely identical to old DB?

Tags: django

I have a web app that I've backed up it's rather modest size DB using:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > backup.json
```

I have created a brand new DB that has many updates to the old schema, but no deletions/renames of objects/rows. However, the new db I would like to use `loaddata` on has some new rows added and models added in addition to what was already there on the old DB which the backup is from. Expectantly, I cannot get the loaddata command to work properly by simply doing the output command `python manage.py loaddata > backup.json`. Is it possible to loaddata from non-identical DBs? Thanks in advance. Just to clarify, none of the old rows or model objects are deleted/renamed. There are only additions of properties to certain objects and new objects altogether.

Comment: Are you using migrations?
What error message are you getting?

Comment: I tried migrating the old fashioned way where I do makemigrations <appname> and then migrate and it has never worked (tried many times, posted stack questions, no longer sure what I'm doing wrong) so I was wondering if this could be a possible workaround if I just backup the old data and make a new DB with the extra/new rows and then load the data back into the old rows as a different way to avoid the migration system. I guess not. And, I'm getting just random errors like "invalid literal for base 10" etc.

Comment: The migration system is usually more robust and easier than most alternatives. You need to figure out why your migration is failing.

Comment: Loaddata will not work if your migrations are messed up. But it's pretty simple to write something similar to loaddata that can populate your database from a dumpdata json file, especially if you don't have a huge amount of models and complicated relations. You can use the json module to read a dump into python data structures which can be used to create model instances.

Comment: Another alternative is to compare the json created by dumpdata from the old and the new databases to figure out exactly what's different. You might be able to manually change the json dump to correspond to the expected format.

Comment: PS: If you want help figuring out what's wrong you have to post your error messages. Exceptions and errors are not "random".